# Reload IP on noip.com in C#

Tags: c#, post, web, request, ip

It is impossible to send a POST request to the correct site: noip.com. 
[Instructions contained here](http://www.noip.com/integrate/request).
Trying to POST request to C#:

```
private void DDD()
        {
            string Host = "";
            string Authorization = "";
            string Authorization_Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Authorization));

            string Zapros = "GET /nic/update?hostname=" + Host + "&myip=1.2.3.4 HTTP/1.0" + "\n"
                + "Host: dynupdate.no-ip.com" + "\n"
                + "Authorization: " + Authorization_Base64 + "\n"
                + "User-Agent: MSA/1.0 msa.com";

            System.Net.HttpWebRequest reqPOST = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update");
            reqPOST.Method = "POST"; 
            reqPOST.Timeout = 120000; 

            byte[] sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Zapros);
            reqPOST.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
            System.IO.Stream sendStream = reqPOST.GetRequestStream();
            sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
            sendStream.Close();

            System.Net.WebResponse result = reqPOST.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream stream = result.GetResponseStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
```

Comment: You're trying to make a POST and a GET request at the same time?. The content of your "Zapros" variable is actually the content and settings for your request and not the content you should have in your request body. If you change the request.Method to "GET" and then the request object should have the Host and authorization part you can assign. (aswell for user-agent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    public static void DynamicUpdate(string hostname, string myip, string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req =
                (HttpWebRequest)
                    HttpWebRequest.Create("http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname=" + hostname + "&myip=" + myip);
            req.Host = "dynupdate.no-ip.com";
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            req.UserAgent = "My awesome update Client/1.0 contact@email.com";
            req.Method = "GET";
            using (var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                // Do something with the response accordingly to
                // http://www.noip.com/integrate/response
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use HttpClient in .NET 4.5:

```
    public static async void DynamicUpdate(string hostname, string myip, string username, string password) {
        try {
            string noipuri = "http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname=" + hostname + "&myip=" + myip;

            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password) }))
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(noipuri))
            using (var content = response.Content) {
                await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        catch {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I’m using Windows IOT Core on a RPI; I’ve jacked around for about ½ day looking for a solution which would work and your sln is perfect. Thanks for sharing!